# How to change the size of the Edge Line in NetowrkX Graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have this image of a network tree, and i just want to make the line between each node smaller, because if i have a huge network the line will be too big and makes other nodes smaller in text.

P.S: I'm using a dictionary for the graph

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLXn.jpg

```
G = nx.Graph(graphDict)
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 100))
pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G, k=0.3, scale=50, seed=101)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_size=10, font_weight='bold', 
        font_color='black', node_size=0,edge_color='lightgrey', width=2)
plt.savefig("Topologie.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't really get the problem I'm afraid - wouldn't simply increasing the `font_size` to e.g. 20 or 30 help here?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how big will the network be, for example each client will have his own network topology, so fixing the size of the edge line will help if it's big

Answer (score 1):

Edges' size has 2 conceptually different aspects - **width** and **length**. Width is configurable and can be easily set per edge, while length is defined by nodes' positioning.

For changing edges' width call draw_networkx_edges, and use the 'width' argument which accepts either float (for constant edge size), or an array of floats.

Changing the length of edges can be done by changing the layout, set by 'pos' argument. The layout defines were each node will be positioned.

Since you have a tree, a reasonable choice would be to use 'dot' positioning as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = nx.DiGraph()
T.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)])
pos = nx.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(T, prog='dot')
nx.draw_networkx(T, pos=pos, arrows= True)
plt.show()
```

In case you chose 'fruchterman_reingold_layout' (aka spring_layout) on purpose, you can play with the 'k' argument to set the right distance between nodes. According to the documentation:

> k : float (default=None)
>           Optimal distance between nodes.  If None the distance is set to
>           1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes.  Increase this value
>           to move nodes farther apart.

Comment: the thing is the dictionary is a variable always, cuz each client of mine will have a different network topology, so i cant put fixed positions manually every time. for example 1 client may have 10 nodes, and others 20.

Comment: You are not required to have fixed positions, `pos` will be generated for each instance according to some positioning algorithm with some parameters. For example, if you'll use `pydot_layout`, you will probably get a nicely displayed tree regardless of the specific topology.

Comment: yeah I figured, because with the spring layout, i was having some trouble with overlapping, so the topology was wrong, but when i changed the layout to another one it works fine.